# Print button in report viewer 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

I using **visual studio 201**5. when rendering an asp.net page that has report viewer.
**Print button** doesn't appear. How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

The print button is an ActiveX control so it only works on Internet Explorer.